# How can I update my skin using the new Minecraft.net?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the new and updated minecraft.net, I tried to download a skin from the skindex, but when I clicked "Upload to Minecraft", it brought me to this page:

[image: Change your sckin, manage your profile, etc]

Then, when I click the link that says "Profile Management" nothing happens. Why won't it show up?

Answer (score 3):

I'll make a step by step guide. You might have encountered a bug or simply have miss clicked.

**Awesome step by step guide!**
**1.** Download the skin and save it on your PC
**2.** Login here: [Minecraft.net login page.](https://minecraft.net/en/login/)
**3.** click your Email address. (see picture)

[image]
**4.** Click "Profile" on the dropdown menu that appears.
**5.** click the "Select a file" to select and upload your new skin (see
picture).[image]

Let me know if you succeeded in updating your skin, or the problem persists. Always happy to help :)

Comment: Op mentioned he got redirected to this page from skindex, so what about adding a step "download skin file from skindex" ? so he'll find his skin file for step 4 easily

Comment: Just FYI, you may want to blackout your email address.

Comment: Thought of it aswell, but its an old email used for nothing else than minecraft. Thanks for the concern anyway @RikerW

Comment: @RustyMembers okay cool. I was more worried about it revealing a name htough.